# How to make overflow-x visible in angular material dialog content

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, angular-material, ng-bootstrap

I'm getting some strang behavior with the mat-dialog-content in angular material dialogs.

I want to show some tooltips (not the angular material tooltips, but those from the ng-bootstrap library, since I want them to have some clickable content). When they overflow to the right, right now, I get a scrollbar, which is not the desired behavior.

I overwrote the default styling with

```
.mat-dialog-content {
    overflow-x: visible !important;
}
```

I still get the scrollbar and the inspection with browser dev tools shows me this:
[image]

Which I find very strange. Even more frustration: when I just exchange 'visible' for 'hidden' that works, but is obviously also not the desired behavior.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the ng-bootstrap library and the very simple solution was to add container="body" to the tooltip triggers.

Answer (score 0):

`position:absolute` should be for both the container (`.tooltip`) as well as for `.tooltiptext`. The relevant **CSS** is:

```
.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black; 
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px 0;
  border-radius: 6px;
  top: -5px;
  left: 105%; 
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

you can check [working demo here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gjj5ec)

The issue which i replicated as per your question can be recreated by changing the css into:

```
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black; 
}
```

Comment: Please excuse my late answer, I was off work last week. Unfortunately, this didn't solve my problem. I tried to put position: absolute on every container inside the tooltip, but I still get the scrollbar. I'm using the tooltips from the ng-bootstrap library btw.